# Deserialize class with an array of base objects into class with an array of inherited objects (Newtonsoft.Json)

Tags: c#, json.net

I've been working on a music game and decided to add conversion of other games' levels. One of the games I decided to convert from uses JSON to store it's levels and so I'm using Newtonsoft.Json for deserializing level data. Level have can 2 object types that are stored in a single array/list with one shared property and one individual property. Keeping that in mind I made level class with it's properties, one base and two inherited classes:

```
class Chart
{
   //Some unimportant properties
   //...

   public Note[] note;

   class Note
   {
      public int[] beat;
   }

   class NoteSingle : Note
   {
      public int x;
   }

   class NoteRain : Note
   {
      public int[] endbeat;
   }
}
```

However, when I try deserialize level, `note` only contains base objects. I tried creating `JsonSerializerSettings` with `TypeNameHandling` set to `All` and passing it to deserialization method, but it didn't worked, `note` still only have base classes in it.

Basically I need to load level from the file, deserialize it as `Chart` and make each of the notes in `note` be one of the types inherited from `Note` depending on json data. Like if note has `x` field then load it as `NoteSingle` and if it has `endbeat` field then load it as `NoteRain`.

Repres

```
class Note
{
    public int[] beat;
}

class NoteSingle : Note
{
    public int x;
}

class NoteRain : Note
{
    public int[] endbeat;
}

class Chart
{
    //Some unimportant properties
    public Note[] note;
    //Some unimportant properties
}

public static void Convert(string path)
{
    string rawData = File.ReadAllText(path);
    JsonSerializerSettings setts = new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
    };
    Chart ch = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Chart>(rawData, setts);

    //Level converter code
}
```

Example data I'm trying to load: https://pastebin.com/zgnRsgWZ

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please give a [mcve] and more explination on what you want to achive. Yes, if you deserialize the type as base type, it will only know the base type properties. Same for any inheritance: if you access `note` from C#, you can also not access `x` and such.

Comment: Basically I need to load all notes from the file into array and make each of them be one of the inherited types depending on json data. Like if note has `x` field then load it as `NoteSingle` and if it has `endbeat` field then load it as `NoteRain`. As for repres give me some time, I'll edit this comment

Comment: You really need to put all the relevant data in the question. Not in the comments like you are doing now. Stack overflow is not a forum. Your situation is very specific. There is no general solution.

Comment: Right, I'll edit the post in a moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try with this code:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
};

var chart = new Chart();
chart.note = new Note[]
{
        new NoteSingle { x = 37 },
        new NoteRain { endbeat = new[] { 9 } }
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(chart, settings);
var chart2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Chart>(json, settings);
```

And it's working. `json` has this value:

```
{
   "$type":"Test.Chart, SoApp",
   "note":{
      "$type":"Test.Chart+Note[], SoApp",
      "$values":[
         {
            "$type":"Test.Chart+NoteSingle, SoApp",
            "x":37,
            "beat":null
         },
         {
            "$type":"Test.Chart+NoteRain, SoApp",
            "endbeat":{
               "$type":"System.Int32[], mscorlib",
               "$values":[
                  9
               ]
            },
            "beat":null
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

And `chart2` has 2 notes of `NoteSingle` and `NoteRain` types. Maybe you aren't using `TypeNameHandling.All` in `Serialize`. You need to use both on `Serialize` and `Deserialize`.

**UPDATE**

If you haven't control of the generated JSON, you can use a Converter to deserialize it:

```
public class YourJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var chart = new Chart();
        var notes = new List<Note>();

        string name = null;
        NoteRain noteRain = null;

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.TokenType)
            {
                case JsonToken.PropertyName:
                    name = reader.Value.ToString();
                    break;
                    
                case JsonToken.Integer:
                    if (name == "x")
                    {
                        var note = new NoteSingle { x = Convert.ToInt32(reader.Value) };
                        notes.Add(note);
                    }
                    else if (name == "endbeat")
                    {
                        if (noteRain == null)
                        {
                            noteRain = new NoteRain { endbeat = new[] { Convert.ToInt32(reader.Value) } };
                            notes.Add(noteRain);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var array = noteRain.endbeat;
                            noteRain.endbeat = new int[noteRain.endbeat.Length + 1];
                                
                            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                            {
                                noteRain.endbeat[i] = array[i];
                            }

                            noteRain.endbeat[noteRain.endbeat.Length - 1] = Convert.ToInt32(reader.Value);
                        }
                    }

                    break;
            }
        }

        chart.note = notes.ToArray();
        return chart;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is a simple example, you must tune it but I think it's easy to do. In the property name I get the name of the property and I use later to create the correct type. If I process a `x` property I know that is a `NoteSingle` and I create it and add to `notes` list.
If, for example, you get a property name like `beat` and you don't know yet the type of the `Note` class, use a temporary variable to store and fill and later, when you read a property that you know is from a concrete class, create the `Note` instance and fill with this variable. And after that, If you read more data of this class, continue filling your instance.

Usage:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.Converters.Add(new YourJsonConverter());
var chart = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Chart>(json, settings);
```

Comment: No, I'm not trying to serialize it, I only need to deserialize data. Here's an example of level I need to load: https://pastebin.com/zgnRsgWZ